# How to force the use of external graphics for selected figures while externalization is enabled?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I would like to force using external graphics (if exist) for a few figures in my document. The following does what I want but document-wide:

```
\tikzset{external/mode=graphics if exists}
```

however, I would like to apply it for selected figures only. 
Is there any command working similar way to

```
\tikzset{external/export next=false}
```

but instead of remaking the `tikz` figure, make `tikz` use the external graphics?

Comment: You can say `\tikzexternaldisable` after `\tikzexternalize` to switch off externalisation globally and then use `\tikzexternalenable` to switch it on for specific images. But I'm not sure if this is what you mean...

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of that method, though it switches of the externalization and LaTeX will compile the tikz image. I am looking for some method, which tell tikz to use external graphics (PDFs generated by tikz) and not compile the tikz image.

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict the application of `external/mode` to the current "scope". In TeX, a "scope" is a group, and a group is (typically) defined by curly braces:

```
{%
\tikzset{external/mode=graphics if exists}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
```

The group can be as huge as needed, but the braces need to be balanced. The comment characters suppress spurious spaces and should be added as in the example.